# How to insert a Loop into a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I know this would be a newbie question, but i have this macro below, and i need it to run from de E16 to E27.

Basicly what i need is to every time the user insert "NA" in one cell of this range, for instance E20, the macro delets the contents of the cell in the same line in the F column, in this case F20, otherwise the macro will insert in that cell F20 the formula (E20-5).

The macro is working fine por one line, but i will need to put a loop and i just don't know how. Could someone help me?

This is the code i'm using:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E16")) Is Nothing Then
    If UCase(Range("E16")) = "NA" Then
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Range("f16").ClearContents
      Application.EnableEvents = True
  Else
     Range("F16").Formula = "=(E16 - 5)"
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need a macro at all in this case? What if you used a formula like `=IF(E16="NA","",E16-5)`? (Put that in F16 and copy downwards.)

Answer (score 1):

## Code:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E16:E27")) Is Nothing Then
        If UCase(Target) = "NA" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0,1).ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
            Target.Offset(0,1).Formula = "=(E16 - 5)"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

## Theory:

You actually don't need a loop here because the Worksheet_Change event is your loop.

Comment: OP Are you sure you don't need the else statement to reference the target cell rather than a hard coded E16?